# prove that $ 1 + (1+a)x + (1+a+a^{2})x^{2}$ + ....$\infty$ is equal to $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-ax)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question**

If $a$,$ x $are real numbers and $|a| < 1$, $|x| < 1$, then prove that $ 1 + (1+a)x + (1+a+a^{2})x^{2}$
+ ....$\infty$ is equal to $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-ax)}$

**Hint:**

$\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{ax}{1-x}+\frac{a^2 x^2}{1-x}+...=\frac{1}{1-x}.(1+ax+a^2 x^2+...)=\frac{1}{1-x}.\frac{1}{1-ax}$

*I can't understand how i would get the step given in the hint from the question since $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is not given in the question but is given in the hint.Except this step i can solve the problem on my own.Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: Any idea about the step given in the hint?

Comment: $1+(1+a)x+(1+a+a^2)x^2+\cdots=1+x+ax+x^2+ax^2+a^2x^2+\cdots$

Comment: did i make any mistake in posting the question?I want to know the reason for -1 vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_n = \frac{1-a}{1-a}+ \frac{1-a^2}{1-a}x + \cdots + \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}x^n \rightarrow$$
$$(1-a)S_n = \sum_{k=0}^nx^k - a\sum_{k=0}^n(ax)^k \rightarrow$$
$$S_n \stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}S = \frac{1}{1-a}(\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{a}{1-ax})= \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-ax)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Expand the brackets and regroup:
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdots)+(ax+ax^2+ax^3+\cdots)+(a^2x^2+a^2x^3+a^2x^4+\cdots)+\cdots=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{ax}{1-x}+\frac{a^2x^2}{1-x}+\cdots=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot (1+ax+a^2x^2+\cdots)=\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot \frac{1}{1-ax}=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-ax)}.$$
Method 2: Use sigma notations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^i \sum_{j=1}^i a^j=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x^i \cdot \frac{1-a^{i+1}}{1-a}=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-a}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i-\frac{a}{1-a}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (ax)^i=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-a}\cdot \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{a}{1-a}\cdot \frac{1}{1-ax}=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-ax)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Replacing "Taylor series" with "geometric series" still keeps everything true, except now it is more easy to understand (summing geometric series is an easy proof).

Do you know how to compute the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{1}{1-ax}$?

Notice that $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)(1+ax+a^2x^2+a^3x^3+\cdots)$ is equal to the sum given in the beginning. (Try and see why this is true for yourself—it's easy.) For $\lvert x\rvert <1$, the left sum is the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{1-x}$, so that gives you the first quantity in the hint. After that, just follow the equalities in the hint.

Also, the sum on the right is the series for $\frac{1}{1-ax}$, given the appropriate bounds on $a$ and $x$. This should immediately prove the problem if you believe that you can multiply Taylor series within their radii of convergence (i.e. you understand why this is true and can prove it perhaps).

Comment: I do understand what you are trying to explain and you are 100% correct but the problem is that Taylor Series is not there in our syllabus.However that won't be a problem since this problem was given in a competitive exam in MCQ pattern.Thanks!

Comment: Replace every mention of Taylor series in my comment with "geometric series". Then everything still holds true, and surely you know why geometric series work this way (formula for summing geometric series?) I apologize as bringing Taylor series into the discussion is unnecessary, because geometric series are just fine here!